# Is there a reference for inner inifinity uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

I want to implement UICollectionView like that img.
uicollectionview has three types of cells.

cell3 is uicollectionview. it grows vertically and Infinitely.

I need a reference.

Comment: nice question .. have you tried anything ?

Comment: do you want to implement collection view inside a collection view ?

Comment: @jawadAli 
i tried but uicollectionView inside uicollectionView with same direction seems to have poor performance.

Comment: @arjunhastir 
That's right, but it doesn't matter if there is another way.

Comment: Yes we can do that , simply create a custom class of UiCollection View with indexpath as property to display your data.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an optional property of the reference type cell in your controller. Then after dequeuing your target cell (Cell3) assing that cell to that property. Now you can use the property as a reference of Cell3.